# DocumentFragments width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In my tests, i create some document fragment with jQuery like:

```
el = $("<span>hello world</span>")
```

Then i make some manipulation with this fragment and want to detect, if element will change its sizes (specially want to detect, if there is a newline). Is there any way, how to detect it without placing fragment into document?

Would love to have something like:

```
el.height() // -> 20
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until you add `el` to the DOM, the `el` has no height.

However you can get the height by append it to DOM, like

`el.hide().appendTo($('body')).height()`

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SZHSE/).

Comment: Are you sure? If you `hide()` the element before calling `height()`, it will always return `0` in my experience.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You can check the demo I added.

Comment: Thanks, I thought i was missing something

Comment: you can set opacity to 0 and still get the height.
the jquery hide function sets display:none